# Running Memnet model using caffe

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I try to use the dataset of mnist, which is an example provided in github, to run Memnet model on the interface of cmd.

The model is downloaded from [here](http://memorability.csail.mit.edu/download.html)

I modified its deploy.prototxt accordingly. Having no idea... Can someone help me with this?

[image: memnet]

But it keeps telling me something wrong going on, as the pic shows:

[image: cmd error]

Answer (score 1):

The command line interface should get as a `-solver` a `solver.prototxt` file (which has `train_val.prototxt` as one of its parameters). You cannot supply `train_val.prototxt` directly to `caffe train`.

You can look at the `examples` subfolder of caffe and find some examples of `solver.prototxt`. A simple one can be found in `examples/mnist`, you can check out [`lenet_solver.prototxt`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/mnist/lenet_solver.prototxt).